# security scenario by using profile

Tags: security, profile

I have 5 users and I have 5 accounts and related contact to account. Now I want user1 and user2 can only view account1 and account2 not any other accounts. And all other users can view all accounts. All the users here have different profiles. How can it be possible to get this scenario working? Please guide me the best ways how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way might be to have a private sharing model set on Account, and ensure that account1 and account2 are shared with user1 and user2. The rest could have the View All permission for Account set on their profiles.

Chances are there are other business requirements at play as well though, and that this setup won't even begin to meet those requirements. I recommend reading the documentation around sharing to make sure that you fully understand how it works.